# Deriving of an addition formula of $\sin$ from a second order differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

How to derive the addition formula of $\sin$:
$$
\sin(t+s)=\sin(t)\cos(s)+\sin(s)\cos(t)
$$

from the following differential equation
$$
y''+y=0.
$$

Comment: Both sides of the first equation are solutions of $y''+y=0$ with the same initial conditions. Note that a solution of  $y''+y=0$ with $y(0)=y_0$ and $y'(0)=y_1$ is unique. Then both sides are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\phi(t)=\sin(t+s)$ and $\psi(t)=\sin t\cos s+\sin s\cos t$ and show that they are solutions of the given differential equation. Show then $\phi(0)=\psi(0)$ and $\phi'(0)=\psi'(0)$ and argue with uniqueness.